# How to create a new page when it reach the bottom

Tags: javascript, outsystems

How to create a new page when it reached the bottom part of the page also it should continue the remaining item in the iteration list.

I'm using an outsystems11 + js to create this reporting.

I already know how to get the current height of my screen the only problem is how can i create a new page to continue the remaining data I need to display.

Comment: You want to build a lazy load system?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a PDF and wanting to control a pagebreak?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .scroll() event to trigger some js function. Just use `RunJavaScript` action in your Preparation, determine the elements by classnames. In Outsystems you can use combination of buttons(which can have "display:none" style) on web forms, and custom javascript in the action I mentioned above in order to bind custom JS logic with your Outsystems logic.